# String splitting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have  sensors data string like this

```
str="A34,B32,C60,D54"
```

I want to split data of every sensor for example A34  for the first sensor that I defined as A and 34 is variable number then I want to remove A and put the number in the first sensor label.

Incoming string from serial port

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to use `String.Split()` function https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = "A34,B32,C60,D54"
Dim substrings As String() = str.Split(","c)
For Each substring As String In substrings
   Console.WriteLine(substring.Remove(0, 1))
Next
```

Comment: Nice mixing of C# and VB.NET.

Comment: That `c` you deleted is valid syntax. Have a look at [What does adding a “c” do in a VB.NET character array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522703/what-does-adding-a-c-do-in-a-vb-net-character-array). Try your code in an IDE with **Option Strict On** and see what happens.

Comment: Indeed it is. `c` is VB.NET's way of declaring a character literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Dim t() As String
Dim Str = "A34,B32,C60,D54"
t = Split(Str, ",")
For Each s In t       
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, "^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$")
    Dim lt As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Dim nb As String = m.Groups(2).Value
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code does the trick. First split the string by the comma to get all the parts, next build a regular expression to separate the number from the letter. Loop over all the parts and match the regular expression. In the match, you'll get the letter and number part.

```
Dim input As String = "A34,B32,C60,D54"
Dim parts As String() = input.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim regex As Regex = new Regex("([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)")

For Each part as String in parts

    Dim result as Match = regex.Match(part)
    Dim letter As String = result.Groups(1).Value
    Dim number As String = result.Groups(2).Value

Next
```

In case the letter part is always 1 character long, you can use the answer of Kapila Perera.