# How to make browser to download the Django CSV file response

Tags: python, django, csv

I am following the Django doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/) to create a CSV file. In my urls.py I have `url(r'^reports/csv_list_report/$',  'csv_list_report')`.

I want user to download the CSV file when clicking on the download button. So I use jQuery for here:

```
$('#download_button').click(function(){
    $.get('/reports/csv_list_report/');
});
```

I can see the response in the firebug, but the browser does not download the file.

Here is my view:

```
def csv_list_report(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reports.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

return response
```

So maybe after the GET I need to write something to handle the response on success? Searched around, there are plenty answers on how to create CSV files, but didn't find any answers including what one need to do to handle the response.

Comment: Why are you trying to use jQuery if you just want to download the file?

Comment: It's trigger the by a click event. I want user to download the file when they click the download button. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make the browser download a file through AJAX (that's what jQuery is doing when you use `$.get`). You have to make a direct synchronous HTTP connection.

Instead of `$.get`, try this:

```
location.replace('/reports/csv_list_report/');
```

**Related:**  [Force download through js or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192917/force-download-through-js-or-query)

Comment: Great, that was the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Would it be a problem that I get a warring from the browser console "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "

Comment: I think that's just a Chrome behavior, it seems you can ignore that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899426/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-css