# Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding

Tags: excel, encoding, csv, utf-8

I have an Excel file that has some Spanish characters (tildes, etc.) that I need to convert to a CSV file to use as an import file.  However, when I do Save As CSV it mangles the "special" Spanish characters that aren't ASCII characters.  It also seems to do this with the left and right quotes and long dashes that appear to be coming from the original user creating the Excel file in Mac.

Since CSV is just a text file I'm sure it can handle a UTF8 encoding, so I'm guessing it is an Excel limitation, but I'm looking for a way to get from Excel to CSV and keep the non-ASCII characters intact.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files ///

Comment: I saw that question before I posted but it is about already having a UTF8 CSV and opening it in Excel not the other way around.

Comment: The answers below seem to work, but they're just workarounds.  Does anyone know how to make Excel do this?

Comment: I wanted to drop my 2 cents:     After a lot of trial and error, attempts to use VBA functions, etc... (I'm using Excel 97 for various reasons)... simply Saving-As to "CSV (MSDOS)" format resolved this issue for me.   In my case, Citrix webinar (GotoWebinar) CSV data ends up with characters to break some Apex code on our end - saving to "CSV (MSDOS)" resolves me (previously) loading the CSV export into Notepad++ and pasting it into a UTF-8 blank file and resaving.   :-P   :-)

Comment: This is a very annoying Excel limitation. I opened a uservoice feature request about this: http://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10006149-support-saving-csv-in-utf-8-encoding, feel free to vote and make it happen

Comment: In my language, excel *automatically* transforms every "..." or "oe" or "ae" in unicode equivalent (…, œ, æ), but when it's time to export, he exclaim _"oh my god, what are thoses characters??"_  Seriously, Microsoft... are you KIDDING?

Comment: @JeffTreuting, this https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0 worked for me.

Comment: according to the Excel uservoice, Microsoft started work on UTF-8 for .csv last month https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10006149-support-saving-csv-in-utf-8-encoding

Comment: Excel uservoice now reports it will be available with Excel 16.0.7466.2023 and later.

Comment: Still can't export tab delimited UTF-8. The ability to specify delimiter and encoding was a feature in open office years ago.

Comment: techlandia.com/guardar-csv-utf8-como_163552 "Save as File Type" -> "CSV (Comma delimited)" -> "Tools" -> "Web Options" "Encoding" > "Save this document as" -> "Unicode (UTF-8)"

Answer (score 423, accepted):

A simple workaround is to use Google Spreadsheet. Paste (values only if you have complex formulas) or import the sheet then download CSV. I just tried a few characters and it works rather well.

NOTE: Google Sheets does have limitations when importing. See [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en).

NOTE: Be careful of sensitive data with Google Sheets.

EDIT: [Another alternative](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/400043-csv-and-unicode-or-utf-8-problem.html) - basically they use VB macro or addins to force the save as UTF8. I have not tried any of these solutions but they sound reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! It's a simple solution, far better that struggling with Excel.

Comment: Added another possibly solution (untested) without having to use Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Perhaps Joel Slotsky (former PM of Excel) could send them his *decade-old* post on [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)?

Comment: With the normal Windows Notepad (using save as, and then choosing utf-8 in the encoding option) worked for me. For me that's the best approach for me since that must be done by users that have no admin rights in their machines, so installing additional software is not required.

Comment: OpenOffice JustWorks(tm) with no hassle - I think it should be included

Comment: I have no experience with OpenOffice but Yessus has submitted something in regards to OpenOffice - if it's not the same thing you should add it as answer

Comment: @nevets1219 I did import the CSV into  Google Spreadsheet but it didn't affect my character issue. Forgetting excel/google and using open office calc did solve my UTF8 issue (inserting my CSV into Excel 2013 as a "text" also failed by the way)

Comment: Uhhh. I just had a shiver down my back. What if your excel file has 200,000 lines? Or contains sensitive data you do not want to include in an excel spreadsheat? Use Openoffice/Libreoffice if you need to.

Comment: @Seb use the solution that fits the problem.  I'm pretty sure Google spreadsheet can handle large files and they are private if you want them to be. Still a local application will do better in both cases if it's available.

Comment: I just tried it - and fyi you need to replace the whole file, not just copy the contents as Excel seems to break the text format of the file not the contents.  Not sure how they broke it but Google Spreadsheets worked perfectly and as expected.

Comment: Here is direct link to Jaimon's UnicodeCSV Addin:  https://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/excel_addin_to_work_with_unicode_csv/

Comment: Google Spreadsheet does not let you choose the delimiter when exporting, so you need to stick with comma if you export a CSV.

Comment: CSV gives you comma delimited and text gives you tab delimited. But I do believe you are correct about delimiters.

Comment: What if the file size is big? Goolge sheet have a size limit around 75M if I remember correctly. I have a file is 700M

Comment: https://techlandia.com/guardar-csv-utf8-como_163552/

"Save as File Type" ->  "CSV (Comma delimited)" -> "Tools"  ->  "Web Options" "Encoding" > "Save this document as" -> "Unicode (UTF-8)"

Comment: Old answer but still valid 10years later. In my case I wanted to keep semicolon separator so I pasted CSV content on GoogleDocs (because there was not this choice of separator on Sheets), exported as .txt & renamed to .csv. Works.

Answer (score 145):

I've found [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)'s spreadsheet application, Calc, is really good at handling CSV data.

In the "Save As..." dialog, click "Format Options" to get different encodings for CSV. [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) works the same way AFAIK.

[image: calc save dialog]

Comment: I'm sure this works, I just don't happen to have OpenOffice already so Google Docs was easier in my situation.  but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: OpenOffice Calc has more and better options when opening and saving "CSV" files (field separators, encoding etc) than both Google Docs and Excel. Also, Google Docs currently suffers from a limit of 400,000 cells per spreadsheet, which OpenOffice Calc does not.

Comment: I can confirm LibreOffice also works: it offers character encoding options on export that are sadly lacking in Excel.

Comment: This is a great option for those working with sensitive data. The OpenOffice suite can be a portable install for those with locked down machines.

Answer (score 122):

1. Save the Excel sheet as "Unicode Text (.txt)". The good news is that all the international characters are in UTF16 (note, not in UTF8). However, the new "*.txt" file is TAB delimited, not comma delimited, and therefore is not a true CSV.
2. (optional) Unless you can use a TAB delimited file for import, use your favorite text editor and replace the TAB characters with commas ",".
3. Import your *.txt file in the target application. Make sure it can accept UTF16 format.

If UTF-16 has been properly implemented with support for non-BMP code points, that you can convert a UTF-16 file to UTF-8 without losing information. I leave it to you to find your favourite method of doing so.

I use this procedure to import data from Excel to Moodle.

Comment: Finally something that worked! Tried the above Excel options on Excel 2013 without success. I just switched to using \t as split character when I parsed it and it worked perfect!

Comment: Needed to export an XLS as CSV to import in MySQL. Using Excel 2003 I exported in format "Unicode Text (.txt)", then used Notepad++ to replace the TAB with `;`, then imported the txt-file into phpmyadmin with default "Character set of the file: utf-8", Format "CSV using LOAD DATA". All encoding was transferred correctly.

Comment: For smaller files and simple data I use this shortcut: select the area or columns that I want to export, then copy (Ctrl+C). Then go to my text editor (for example, Gedit in Ubuntu) and paste. The text editor has all the data as TAB delimited. Then save as a text file, usually in UTF8. The final format may depend on your text editor configuration.

Comment: That's the best workaround for me! Now I can import import files via phpMyAdmin easily!

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Why MS still refuses to use UTF as a standard beats me.

Comment: Obviously (2) has a limitation - if any column has a comma (,) in it, then you have to quote that column.  (Or does the international option quote all columns?)

Comment: @OskarLimka: When you say "UTF", do you mean UTF-8 or UTF-16? Because Microsoft does use UTF-16 quite a bit.

Comment: @Flimm, I meant UTF-8, I'm not very familiar with UTF-16 as in my work I need to have full compatibility with previous ASCII and ISO-8859-1 files.  I'm not sure UTF-16 is backward compatible in this respect.

Comment: Some characters get converted to "TAB" character on the file I tried this method

Comment: *"The good news is that all the international characters are in UTF16 (note, not in UTF8)."*: **complete nonsense**. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are two ways to encode the whole set of Unicode code points.

Comment: @Kai Noack, if you are using Notepad++ anyway, you can just open the original non utf-8 csv and change the encoding from the Encoding option on the menu bar (might save you a few steps).

Comment: It doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 46):

I know this is an old question but I happened to come upon this question while struggling with the same issues as the OP.

Not having found any of the offered solutions a viable option, I set out to discover if there is a way to do this just using Excel.

Fortunately, I have found that the lost character issue only happens (in my case) when saving from xlsx format to csv format.  I tried saving the xlsx file to xls first, then to csv.  It actually worked.

Please give it a try and see if it works for you.  Good luck.

Comment: For me, on Excel for Mac 2011, this works but only if I choose `Windows comma separated (CSV)`. It doesn't work if I use the default or DOS CSV options - both these replace the accented characters with random junk characters. Tested for characters including `é`,`è`,`â`... Don't know if it's real UTF8 but the characters aren't mangled.

Comment: Quick confirmation - the files produced with this method on (Excel for Mac 2011) **do not** produce UTF-8 csvs, **BUT**, they do produce CSVs that at least contain the correct characters and can therefore can be **painlessly converted to UTF8 in a text editor**, which is a big step forward from the ludicrous mangled junk that Excel spits out by default.

Comment: Yes, agreed, this worked for me as well (Excel Mac 2011) and it really deserves more upvotes.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me (using Excel 2007). I had 2 non-ASCII characters in my file and one of them was saved OK this way, the other wasn't.

Comment: Note that the resulting CSV file will be in UTF-16, not UTF-8 as the question asked.

Answer (score 38):

You can use [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) command under Unix (also available on Windows as [libiconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)).

After saving as CSV under Excel in the command line put:

```
iconv -f cp1250 -t utf-8 file-encoded-cp1250.csv > file-encoded-utf8.csv
```

(remember to replace cp1250 with your encoding).

Works fast and great for big files like post codes database, which cannot be imported to GoogleDocs (400.000 cells limit).

Comment: That is useless if your content contains characters which can not be encoded in 1250, a better way would be to export as "Unicode .txt" in Excel and use iconv to convert from Utf16. Maybe also do a `sed` or `tr` to translate from '\t' to ','

Comment: Excel's default encoding seems to be CP858 when saving as CSV or MS-DOS CSV, and Windows 1252 when saving as Windows CSV (as tested on Excel for Mac 2011).

Comment: I completely agree that this is useless, as when Excel saves in .csv format, it loses information when it comes to Unicode code points that can't be encoded in a one-byte-per-code-point encoding.

Answer (score 36):

You can do this on a modern Windows machine without third party software. This method is reliable and it will handle data that includes quoted commas, quoted tab characters, CJK characters, etc.

**1. Save from Excel**

In Excel, save the data to `file.txt` using the type `Unicode Text (*.txt)`.

**2. Start PowerShell**

Run `powershell` from the Start menu.

**3. Load the file in PowerShell**

```
$data = Import-Csv C:\path\to\file.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding BigEndianUnicode
```

**4. Save the data as CSV**

```
$data | Export-Csv file.csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This method worked perfectly for a CSV file with over 15,000 records, with lines of more than the 1024 character limit imposed by Notepad.  Takes seconds, and doesn't use third party software.  Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, even when I tried using Google Sheets, I ran into the same problem. So maybe this PowerShell strategy would have worked. Here was my problem. For certain characters such as certain emojis, you need to use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959780/470749

Comment: @Ryan That issue is specific to MySQL. I just tried the problematic character in that question and it worked fine in both Excel and PowerShell.

Comment: Worked wonderfully! It's also possible to pipe the two commands together directly: `Import-Csv ... | Export-Csv ...` without using an intermediate `$data` variable.

Answer (score 26):

The only "easy way" of doing this is as follows. First, realize that there is a difference between what is displayed and what is kept hidden in the Excel .csv file.

1. Open an Excel file where you have the info (.xls, .xlsx)
2. In Excel, choose "CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv) as the file type and save as that type.
3. In NOTEPAD (found under "Programs" and then Accessories in Start menu), open the saved .csv file in Notepad
4. Then choose -> Save As... and at the bottom of the "save as" box, there is a select box labelled as "Encoding". Select UTF-8 (do NOT use ANSI or you lose all accents etc). After selecting UTF-8, then save the file to a slightly different file name from the original.

This file is in UTF-8 and retains all characters and accents and can be imported, for example, into MySQL and other database programs.

This answer is taken from [this forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/400043-csv-and-unicode-or-utf-8-problem.html).

Comment: This is incorrect, because of step 2, saving as CSV. The trouble with this is that Excel save the CSV file in cp1252, which is a one-byte-per-code-point encoding. This leads to loss of information for the characters which can't fit in one byte.

Comment: It worked for me, but i cannot understand why. My file generated by javascript is always read incorrectly in excel (as a different encoding). But when i open in notepad and save as utf-8, it works fine! So, looks like there is a metadata with the encoding.

How it works? If notepad can save UTF-8 CSV files and Excel can read them, it's possible in my program generate correct UTF-8 CSV files, that Excel can read?

Comment: Worked for me. In an XSLX converted from Access. Diacritics and LF-only and ISO-date formats are all OK. One or another did not work with more popular solutions.

Answer (score 22):

Another one I've found useful:
"**Numbers**" allows encoding-settings when saving as CSV.

Comment: ^ it's an application in Mac OSX

Comment: also be careful with Numbers as it has limitation in the number of rows, and I have converted data like this before not realizing it had cropped some of it.
Excel/CSV has much higher limits.

Answer (score 16):

#### Using Notepad++

This will fix the corrupted CSV file saved by Excel and re-save it in the proper encoding.

- Export CSV from Excel
- Load into Notepad++
- Fix encoding
- Save

Excel saves in CP-1252 / Windows-1252. Open the CSV file in Notepad++. Select

```
Encoding > Character Sets > Western European > Windows-1252
```

Then

```
Encoding > Convert to UTF-8
File > Save
```

First tell Notepad++ the encoding, *then* convert. Some of these other answers are converting without setting the proper encoding first, mangling the file even more. They would turn what should be `’` into `達`. If your character does not fit into CP-1252 then it was already lost when it was saved as CSV. Use another answer for that.

Comment: I may get this wrong, but you can't save the file as a ".csv" in Notepad++ and thats what this is about.

Comment: Yes you can. You are only just saving a text file, and `.csv` is a text file. This answer will open the CSV file corrupted by Excel, fix it, then re-save it with the proper encoding.

Comment: What you are communicating has far reaching consequences. Employing this eminent method, we can attain a higher data quality! Bravo! (Quiz: why is this comment so quizzical?)

Answer (score 14):

"nevets1219" is right about Google docs, however if you simply "import" the file it often does not convert it to UTF-8.

But if you import the CSV into an existing Google spreadsheet it does convert to UTF-8.

Here's a recipe:

- On the main Docs (or Drive) screen click the "Create" button and choose "Spreadsheet"
- From the "File" menu choose "Import"
- Click "Choose File"
- Choose "Replace spreadsheet"
- Choose whichever character you are using as a Separator
- Click "Import"
- From the "File" menu choose "Download as" -> CSV (current sheet)

The resulting file will be in UTF-8

Comment: The trouble with this answer is how you generated the CSV file in the first place. If you did that by simpling saving as CSV in Excel, the CSV file will be in cp1252, which is a one-byte-per-code-point encoding. This will lead to loss of information when it comes to characters that cannot fit in one byte.

Comment: Well, that's a problem with any of these answers. And will be with any answer to how to convert to UTF-8 since there's no way to know or control what the original encoding was.

Comment: Some of the answers do talk about how to get round that issue, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15500052/247696

Answer (score 13):

Under Excel 2016 and up (including Office 365), there is a CSV option dedicated to the UTF-8 format.

In Office 365, do Save As; where previously one might have chosen CSV (Comma Delimited), now one of the file types you can save as is **CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)**

Comment: You should provide some instructions on how to use that option.

Comment: @dexgecko sure: it's called the "Save" button/menu. There are now four CSV export types in Excel 2016 on Windows: **CSV** saves as "ANSI" (more or less equivalent Latin1, but that may be different with a non-western OS install, I'm not sure), **UTF-8 CSV** saves as UTF-8 with BOM, CSV (DOS) saves as CP850 (again, mais depend on the install?) and CSV (Mac) saves as MacRoman.

Comment: However, Excel will only be able to read UTF-8 and ANSI CSV files (Excel can use the BOM to choose). To import from another encoding, rename as .txt, open from Excel (you have then a long list of encodings to choose from), and since it won't interpret the separator correctly, use the "convert" button to split the rows. You can also use this trick when importing a CSV from a different language convention (in french for instance, the filed separator is a semicolon, as the comma is already used as decimal separator).

Comment: A bit OT, but anyway: it is simpler with VBA, as you can use the **Origin** argument of [Workbook.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) when you open a CSV file. But this will only work with the few encodings available for CSV. One may use [Workbook.OpenText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel), for which the **Origin** can be any encoding, alas that does not work for a CSV file encoded in UTF-8 without BOM! But if the file has the .txt extension, it works! Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Strange, I don't see a UTF-8 CSV option in my Excel 2016.

Comment: @dexgecko Strange, indeed. According to [this page](http://micka39.info/2016/11/17/office-2016365-excel-permet-dexporter-en-csv-avec-lencodage-utf-8/) (in french, sorry), the functionality was added in november 2016, in build version 1610. I have currently the 1802 version. However, I thought only Office 365 had that kind of evolutions, and I'm using Office Pro 2016 (not the 365 flavor). Maybe try to update your Office.

Comment: @dexgecko A quick check on https://products.office.com/ seems to show the professional "one time" version is not sold any longer though. I don't know what happens to those like me who have this product. Thanks for having pointed this out!

Comment: FWIW, This works on Excel 2016 version 1909 build 12026.20334. I'm pretty sure it did not work properly until a few weeks ago, cause I had to resort to Nick's solution above to keep diacritics intact. Possibly the fix was not in Excel itself, but in a Windows update.

Answer (score 9):

What about using Powershell.

```
Get-Content 'C:\my.csv' | Out-File 'C:\my_utf8.csv' -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: The text of non-ascii Spanish characters will be changed from the original Spanish character to the encode string used by ANSI.  So, the text will not be the same as the original.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for an entirely programmatic (or at least server-side) solution, I've had great success using catdoc's xls2csv tool.

Install catdoc:

```
apt-get install catdoc
```

Do the conversion:

```
xls2csv -d utf-8 file.xls > file-utf-8.csv
```

This is blazing fast.

Note that it's important that you include the `-d utf-8` flag, otherwise it will encode the output in the default `cp1252` encoding, and you run the risk of losing information.

Note that `xls2csv` also only works with `.xls` files, it does not work with `.xlsx` files.

Comment: Or choose a different output encoding, can't fix everyone's problems with a single answer :-)

Comment: I know it's unfortunate, but the fact is that this answer *will* cause problems for some users. The fact that you've only ever run this with characters that fit in cp1252 is just lucky, you provided no warning about this risk in the answer, you just said that it "worked without a hitch". You've not been asked to fix everyone's problems, just OP's, which a lot of people share.

Comment: There you go, I fixed the issue in the answer post and removed the downvote.

Answer (score 7):

**Easiest way:**
*No need Open office and google docs*

1. Save your file as "Unicode text file";
2. now you have an unicode text file
3. open it with "notepad" and "Save as" it with selecting "utf-8" or
   other code page that you want
4. rename file extension from "txt" to "csv". This will result in a tab-delimited UTF-8 csv file.
5. If you want a *comma*-delimited file, open the `csv` file you just renamed and replace all tabs with commas. To do this in Notepad on Win 10, simply select one tab field then click `Ctrl+H`. In the window that opens, type a comma `,` in the "Replace with" field then click "Replace All". Save your file. The result will be a comma-delimited UTF-8 csv file.

**Don't open it with MS-Office anyway!!!**
**Now you have a tab delimited CSV file.**
Or, a comma-delimited one if you applied step number 5.

Comment: For a tab delimited file it may be better to use a `.txt` extension. `csv`, i.e. comma separated files, is just confusing.

Answer (score 5):

As funny as it may seem, the easiest way I found to save my 180MB spreadsheet into a UTF8 CSV file was to select the cells into Excel, copy them and to paste the content of the clipboard into SublimeText.

Comment: This works because Excel provides a [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) version of the selection via the clipboard. You can equally well use Notepad instead of SublimeText but just remember to save with UTF-8 encoding if you do!

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to find a VBA solution for this problem on Mac Excel.  There simply seemed to be no way to output UTF-8 text.

So I finally had to give up on VBA, bit the bullet, and learned AppleScript.  It wasn't nearly as bad as I had thought.

Solution is described here:
http://talesoftech.blogspot.com/2011/05/excel-on-mac-goodbye-vba-hello.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an Windows environment, save and work with the file as usual in Excel but then open up the saved Excel file in Gnome Gnumeric (free). Save Gnome Gnumeric's spreadsheet as CSV which - for me anyway - saves it as UTF-8 CSV.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to do it: download open office ([here](http://www.openoffice.org/)), load the spreadsheet and open the excel file (`.xls` or `.xlsx`). Then just save it as a text CSV file and a window opens asking to keep the current format or to save as a .ODF format. select "keep the current format" and in the new window select the option that works better for you, according with the language that your file is been written on. For Spanish language select Western Europe (`Windows-1252/ WinLatin 1`) and the file works just fine. If you select Unicode (`UTF-8`), it is not going to work with the spanish characters.

Comment: There is no reason why UTF-8 would not work with Spanish characters.

Answer (score 3):

1. Save xls file (Excel file) as Unicode text=>file will be saved in text format (.txt)
2. Change format from .txt to .csv (rename the file from XYX.txt to XYX.csv

Comment: This doesn't work because your instructions don't include the necessary step of converting tabs to commas in the file data.

Comment: Excel's "Unicode text" is UTF-16, not UTF-8 as asked for in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I have also came across the same problem but there is an easy solution for this.

1. Open your xlsx file in Excel 2016 or higher.
2. In "Save As" choose this option: "(CSV UTF-8(Comma Delimited)*.csv)"

It works perfectly and a csv file is generated which can be imported in any software. I imported this csv file in my SQLITE database and it works perfectly with all unicode characters intact.

Comment: This option isn't available in my copy of Excel 2016. Are you using the Office 365 version?

Answer (score 2):

Came across the same problem and googled out this post. None of the above worked for me. At last I converted my Unicode .xls to .xml (choose Save as ... XML Spreadsheet 2003) and it produced the correct character. Then I wrote code to parse the xml and extracted content for my use.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small Python script that can export worksheets in UTF-8.

You just have to provide the Excel file as first parameter followed by the sheets that you would like to export. If you do not provide the sheets, the script will export all worksheets that are present in the Excel file.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# export data sheets from xlsx to csv

from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
from os import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

def get_all_sheets(excel_file):
    sheets = []
    workbook = load_workbook(excel_file,use_iterators=True,data_only=True)
    all_worksheets = workbook.get_sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        sheets.append(worksheet_name)
    return sheets

def csv_from_excel(excel_file, sheets):
    workbook = load_workbook(excel_file,use_iterators=True,data_only=True)
    for worksheet_name in sheets:
        print("Export " + worksheet_name + " ...")

        try:
            worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        except KeyError:
            print("Could not find " + worksheet_name)
            sys.exit(1)

        your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            lrow = []
            for cell in row:
                lrow.append(cell.value)
            wr.writerow(lrow)
        print(" ... done")
    your_csv_file.close()

if not 2 <= len(sys.argv) <= 3:
    print("Call with " + sys.argv[0] + " <xlxs file> [comma separated list of sheets to export]")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    sheets = []
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        sheets = list(sys.argv[2].split(','))
    else:
        sheets = get_all_sheets(sys.argv[1])
    assert(sheets != None and len(sheets) > 0)
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1], sheets)
```

Comment: I have updated the implementation a bit and created a gist https://gist.github.com/julianthome/2d8546e7bed869079ab0f409ae0faa87

Answer (score 2):

Excel typically saves a csv file as ANSI encoding instead of utf8.

One option to correct the file is to use Notepad or Notepad++:

1. Open the .csv with Notepad or Notepad++.
2. Copy the contents to your computer clipboard.
3. Delete the contents from the file.
4. Change the encoding of the file to utf8.
5. Paste the contents back from the clipboard.
6. Save the file.

Comment: Not sure about old versions of NP++, but in the current version you can just select Encoding > Convert to UTF-8. replaces steps 2-5

Answer (score 1):

A second option to "nevets1219" is to open your CSV file in Notepad++ and do a convertion to ANSI.

Choose in the top menu :
Encoding -> Convert to Ansi

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted. Notepad++ did it for me. Can't store my file in Google Spreadsheet as it is confidential.

Comment: The trouble with this answer is how you generate the CSV file in the first place. If you simply save as CSV from Excel, the encoding will be cp1252, which is a one-byte-per-code-point encoding, and therefore will lose information for characters that don't fit into that. Also, at the end, you should convert to UTF-8, and not to Ansi, if you want to do what the question asked for.

Comment: This is by far the easier answer IMO. I'm using Excel 2016 and found it save to ANSI encoding by default, but got it into UTF-8 which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Encoding -> Convert to Ansi will encode it in ANSI/UNICODE. Utf8 is a subset of Unicode. Perhaps in ANSI will be encoded correctly, but here we are talking about UTF8, @SequenceDigitale.

There are faster ways, like exporting as csv ( comma delimited ) and then, opening that csv with Notepad++ ( free ), then Encoding > Convert to UTF8. But only if you have to do this once per file. If you need to change and export fequently, then the best is LibreOffice or GDocs solution.

Comment: "Utf8 is a subset of Unicode": this makes no sense. UTF-8 is an *encoding* of Unicode.

Comment: I'm not sure I can find this "Encoding -> Convert to Ansi" option.

Comment: Simply a ANSI csv in Notepad++ and changing the encoding of the file to utf8 causes the original non-ascii Spanish characters to be converted into encode strings which do not match the original text.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Excel has an option to export spreadsheet using Unicode encoding. See following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: "Unicode Text" saves in UTF-16 LE (Little Endian), not in UTF-8 as asked by the OP.

Comment: Yes, but it is the best way to get Unicode support for your x-separated-values in Excel. I've had all sorts of issues trying to get Excel to play ball with UTF-8! [Read More](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Excel-Using-Microsoft-Excel-as-Unicode-Text-Editor.html)

Answer (score 1):

open .csv fine with notepad++. if you see your encoding is good (you see all characters as they should be) press encoding , then convert to ANSI
else - find out what is your current encoding

Comment: that worked for me.. had problem with greek characters when exportedmysql db as csv and imported it to excel..

Comment: The problem with this is how you generate the CSV file in the first place. If you simply save as CSV file in Excel, it will save it in cp1252, which is a one-byte-per-code-point encoding, and therefore loses information.

Answer (score 1):

another solution is to open the file by winword and save it as txt and then reopen it by excel and it will work ISA

Answer (score 1):

Save Dialog > Tools Button > Web Options > Encoding Tab

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The way I understand it it only takes effect when saving as a web format (HTML etc.), not when saving as CSV.

Comment: Works for me - office 2007

Comment: not working on office 2010 choosing any CSV profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and come across [this](https://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/excel_addin_to_work_with_unicode_csv/) add in  , and it works perfectly fine in excel 2013 beside excel 2007 and 2010 which it is mention for.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to automate this process on my Mac. I originally tried using `catdoc/xls2csv` as suggested by mpowered, but `xls2csv` had trouble detecting the original encoding of the document and not all documents were the same. What I ended up doing was setting the default webpage output encoding to be `UTF-8` and then providing the files to Apple's Automator, applying the `Convert Format of Excel Files` action to convert to `Web Page (HTML)`. Then using `PHP`, `DOMDocument` and `XPath`, I queried the documents and formatted them to `CSV`.

This is the PHP script (process.php):

```php
<?php
$pi = pathinfo($argv[1]);
$file = $pi['dirname'] . '/' . $pi['filename'] . '.csv';
$fp = fopen($file,'w+');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($argv[1]);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$table = [];
foreach($xpath->query('//tr') as $row){
    $_r = [];
    foreach($xpath->query('td',$row) as $col){
        $_r[] = trim($col->textContent);
    }
    fputcsv($fp,$_r);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

And this is the shell command I used to convert the HTML documents to csv:

```
find . -name '*.htm' | xargs -I{} php ./process.php {}
```

This is a really, really roundabout way of doing this, but it was the most reliable method that I found.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to open the UTF-8 CSV file in Notepad where it will be displayed correctly.
Then replace all the "," with tabs.
Paste all of this into a new excel file.

Comment: The question is about converting an Excel file to a UTF-8 encoded CSV file. This answer starts with a UTF-8 encoded CSV file!

Answer (score -1):

And for those who have sublime text: save with encoding utf-16 LE with BOM should do it ;-)

Comment: Nope, because UTF-16 is not the same as UTF-8, which is what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

(On a Mac:) From Excel save as CSV file. Open the CSV file in [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (it’s free) and use "save as". In the save dialog choose Unicode (UTF-8). Done

(I guess you can do this with TextEdit also - if you play with the open and save settings. Try Open files: auto, Save files: UTF-8)

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that it is lossy. If you have code points that don't fit in a one-byte-per-code-point encoding, then those characters will get lost in the transition.

Answer (score -3):

I used the following solution: Mac Exel 2008 > file > Save-as and then under format use MS_DOS Comma Separated (.csv). Worked perfect.

Comment: The question was specifically about UTF-8.

Comment: It does't help.

Answer (score -3):

You can save `excel` as `unicode` text, it is tab-delimited.

Comment: It is an answer in the sense that it results in a tab-delimited (rather than comma-delimited) file, which is something most people (including me) can work with.

Comment: "Unicode text" in Excel means UTF-16, and not UTF-8, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: This is exactly what worked for me. The question is, for most people, not whether the file is encoded in UTF-8 but whether the 'special' characters are preserved. The fact that Excel doesn't do this, in 2016, forces us to jump through hoops.