# encoding from any language to utf in php

Tags: php

I insert from csv characters from different languages..

I apply this to every set of characters:

```
    private function process_elements($element){
       utf8_encode($element);
      return $element;
}
```

The problem is when they go into the database, they go like this:

```
???????? ?? ???????????? ????? ??????? ??? ???????...
```

When I retrieve them from the databse, I also get this.

This happens with greek. However, when I retrieve greek pages (through scrapping), who are on a utf encoded page. The characters look like this:

```
Î”ÎµÏ‚ webcam Î´Ï‰Î¼Î¬Ï„Î¹Î± | Gr.ImLive.com
```

which is okay, because when i use the utf8_encode function, they look normal on the screen..

But when the data is taken from the csv and be put into the database, i get those question marks..

Is there a way to encode form any language to utf.. why retrieving data from csv and a utf8 encoded webpage makes such a difference.. they look the same.. how do I address that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look at this

it will help you

[Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Also: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) :)

Comment: does it talk about how to convert greek letters from csv file and then encoding them to utf.. cause that seems to be the problem.. I get those ??? characters whenever taking data and putting them into database..with the utf8_encode function and without it :(

Comment: in other words, i can fetch a utf document and translate it successfully, cause i do scrapping on google which uses utf.. so there is no problem with that..but when i get the data from a file, it has some encoding (it is an excel file)..the greek words look like this ???

Answer (score 1):

It's not about "languages", it's about *encodings*. Text is encoded as bits and bytes. Any one byte is equal to any other byte. If you only have a blob of bytes, you cannot know what encoding it represents. You can *guess*, but that's not accurate. You have to *know* what encoding some text is in by reading the accompanying meta data. That may be documentation, a `<meta>` tag or an HTTP header. Then you need to treat the text in that encoding.

`utf8_encode` actually *converts* text **from ISO-8859-1** to UTF-8. It does not simply encode *anything* to UTF-8, because it does not have the means to determine what something is encoded in either. If your text is already UTF-8 encoded or was not ISO-8859-1 encoded to begin with, you're just garbling the text (as you are).

Comment: i know that.. it is correct.. the problem is really not in the utf8 encode.. but the greek data that i obtain from the csv file..Example: Δες webcam δωμάτια
 when i put it into the database, with or without any encoding i get this ??????.. how do i deal with that

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file?

Comment: i think i found the solution it is to encode the excel through google docs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding   .. the solution is not a php solution

Comment: You can do it with PHP as well, you just need to figure out what encoding the text is encoded in, then convert it specifically from that encoding to UTF-8.