# Interop.Excel UTF-8 encoding when saving file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, encoding

I'm having an issue saving an Excel file as a CSV with UTF-8 encoding.

Because I have non standard characters (different language) in my Excel document it caused issues when saved as a CSV. This [was solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745566/excel-xls-to-csv-with-utf-8) by setting the web options encoding to UTF-8.

I am creating a basic C# program that parses data from an Excel file and saves it in CSV format but I cant get it to save using the UTF-8 encoding.

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to work with the Excel files.

This is my code:

```
private Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };
private Excel.Workbook Workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(OrigionalFileUrl);
Workbook.SaveAs(NewFileUrl);
```

I have tried setting

```
application.DefaultWebOptions.Encoding = MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
```

but it doesnt work and the CSV file that I get is always a mess when it comes to sections with special characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to do that on the workbook level, not on the application.  Also, it's possible because you didn't include the file format as CSV that the `SaveAs` is using the native format but only changing the file extension.

Try these and see if they address your issue:

```
Workbook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
Workbook.SaveAs(NewFileUrl, XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution didn't work for me. But according to the documentation there is now a
XlFileFormat for CSV-UTF8:

```
XlFileFormat.xlCSVUTF8
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Comment: .net works via interop, not via vba api. interop api has no such option: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat