# How to export Excel file with arabic characters to CSV file?

Tags: excel, csv

I try to convert excel file that includes arabic letters to CSV format, but I got interogation points(???) instead of the arabic letters. 
Can anyone tell me how to conserve the letters.

Comment: Here is a discussion on similar stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding

Comment: Press save as and than select as datatype comma seperated values