# Excel to Tab delimited (.txt) file with special character

Tags: excel, utf-8, excel-2010, office-2010, export-to-text

I want to export Excel to Tab delimited (.txt) file with special character.

I've changethe format to UTF-8, but it still doesnt work.

The origin data is like `Mädchen` and what i got is `M?dchen`

Anyone can help me? Thank you

Comment: Do you want the delimiter to be a special character or are you referring to the characters in the data?

Comment: I want to export the excel to a text file with tab delimiter. And I want to extract the special characters on the new file. I dont know if i explain clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to save the file as an Unicode text file. And save as the unicode text file, change the encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 2):

This was similarly asked and answered before: [Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding). Take a look at Eric's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as Unicode text file. It will still save as Tab Delimited and preserve all the versatile non-English characters.

Comment: Isn't this a rephrase of the accepted answer of @TrueBlue10?