# How to insert a degree symbol into excel

Tags: excel, csv, symbols, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to type a degree symbol into an excel document which is then being saved out as a .csv document before finally being imported into InDesign via an add on called Easycatalog. Having no luck with keeping the degree symbol as a degree symbol when it comes into InDesign and wondered if anyone can help with this.

I'm variably getting lots of other symbols but never the degree symbol. Someone has suggested it is a font encoding issue and said I should use Unicode but not sure how to even specify an excel doc exports with Unicode character encoding.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Hold down alt and press 248 then release alt.  ASCII character codes show this: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/degree-symbol-ascii-code-248.html

However if encoding is really the problem: 
[Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding) may help.

and a good read on the problem you have:http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html