# R problems with non-English characters

Tags: r, non-english

I'm getting some location info from Twitter and I can't get the foreign language characters to come out right when I convert the list into data frame.
For example, I have this code:

```
x <- rbind('МоскваРоссия','knoxfieldmelbourne', 'CA US','MelbrneAustralia')
y <- data.frame(rbind('МоскваРоссия','knoxfieldmelbourne', 'CA US','MelbrneAustralia'))

write.csv(x,'\\test2.csv')
```

If I just read out 'x' in the console I get:

```
> x
     [,1]                
[1,] "МоскваРоссия"      
[2,] "knoxfieldmelbourne"
[3,] "CA US"             
[4,] "MelbrneAustralia"
```

But when I write X into csv or when I look at it in viewer I get:
[image]

I'm running on Windows and using Excel to open CSV file.

If I run 'y' in the console I get the same result as above.
Obviously R can read non-English characters but why does it change when I copy it to csv?

Comment: What OS are you using (Windows does not use UTF-8 by default)? What "viewer" are you using? What are you using to look at the csv file with?

Comment: I've edited my post. The viewer is R Studio viewer. I'll keep trying to use the code from the post mentioned by @Pascal but its not working for me at the moment.

Comment: If you really need excel, try opening the csv using Google Spreadsheet and then exporting to xlsx.  More discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Those are Russian characters. Unless you're working with a lot of different languages and don't know which is which, simply changing the R locale should work.
Also, the file encoding needs to be UTF.

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Russian")
write.csv(x,'\\test2.csv',fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```