# Excel to CSV with special characters

Tags: excel

This question's asked before. [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419778/excel-to-csv-with-special-characters) given on this post works only for some of the special characters. When i save the file with Utf-8, some characters are saved as question marks in the CSV file. For example, this character ∑ is saved as ? mark in the csv file.

Is there another encoding method that I should use?

The file that I want to save includes these special characters : `∏∑€₭₮₲₽£¥§ßØæŒƂƌƜȹȻɄɅɸͶΏΨπλЖяӨ`

Comment: do you see the ? when you re-open the file in excel or if you open it in another program? 
I tried it on my mac and it just works fine when I save to csv with these characters

Comment: yes, I see the question mark when I open the saved csv file with notepad or excel (no difference). I use windows 10.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Are you certain you are saving it as `CSV UTF-8` and then opening it in Notepad (or Editing it)?

Comment: yes, I save it as CSV utf-8 and open it with notepad to check it.

Comment: I found a workaround. The vba macro offered by Bryn solves my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688311/export-sheet-as-utf-8-csv-file-using-excel-vba Other solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: @Max What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I have Excel 2010.

Comment: @Max I think (not sure) that the ability to save as `CSV UTF-8` was not available (as a save option) until Excel 2016, so using `ADO` as in Bryn's macro is the way for you to go.

Comment: @Max I found this on a Google search:  [A simple way to UTF-8 encode your CSV file using Excel 2010](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zh/SSWU4L/Data/imc_Data/Data_q_a_watson_assistant/A_Simple_Way_to_UTF-8_Encode_your_CSV_fi191.html).  I wonder if it would work for you.

Comment: I tried this method, but I couldn't make it work unfortunately.

Comment: "macro offered by Bryn solves my problem" <-- so this Q can be considered as solved? ( :

Comment: yes, it is solved. thanks.