# How to load different language into dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I try to load my excel file with:

```
pd.read_excel(filename)
```

It does not make a a **Dataframe** unless I delete the column with the french (i.e Vérité, café). I tried switching the `encoding='utf-8'` but it didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: I very much doubt the Excel file is actually saved as `utf-8`. Check the encoding of the file, or open it in Excel and save it with the correct encoding.

Comment: What do you mean with *'it does not make a dataframe'*? Do you get an error message? If so, please show that.

Comment: You probably want to find out how to save csv data from excel in a certain encoding, check this other stackoverflow answer for help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4221256/3730397

Comment: @joris the error is [Decode error - output not utf-8][Finished]

Comment: firelynx, i'll check it out thanks.

Comment: @AndyDo I meant the original call without specifying the encoding.