# Import a csv file containing Hindi text into sql Lite browser

Tags: sqlite, unicode, non-english

I have an `.xls` sheet containing a list of `English` words with corresponding  `Hindi` words,

I converted it into a csv format file, I need to import this into the sqllite browser, when I do so , the Hindi words appear as question marks?

Is it unsupported?

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Choose an **encoding** that supports those characters

Comment: Tell Excel to export the CSV encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Please refer encoding used in sqlite, also while exporting to CSV, make usre you are using UTF-8 or UTF-16 for better support of HINDI in the CSV file..

Comment: thank you , exporting it to UTF-8 worked.

Comment: @messa2703 Happy that it worked for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best ways is save your data in xlxs format. and when you need to generate csv file paste this data to google sheet and download that file as csv file.
this is a reference link
[Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)