# Importing .csv files with "special" characters

Tags: r, excel, encoding

I'm trying to read a .csv file into R. The .csv file was created in Excel, and it contains "long" dashes, which are the result of Excel "auto-correcting" the sequence space-dash-space. Sample entries that contain these "long" dashes:

> US – California – LA
>   US – Washington – Seattle

I've experimented with different encoding, including the following three options:

```
x <- read.csv(filename, encoding="windows-1252") # Motivated by http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=551123
x <- read.csv(filename, encoding="latin1")
x <- read.csv(filename, encoding="UFT-8")
```

But, the long dashes either show up as � (first and second option) or as `<U+0096>` (third option).

I realize that I can store the file in different formats or use different software ([Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)) but that's not the point.

Has anyone figured out what encoding option in R works in such cases?

Comment: For the third option, you can also clean your data afterwards with for example `gsub("<U+0096>", "", x, fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RStudio, use Import Dataset.

- Use Heading: No
- Separator Whitespace
- Decimal Period
- Quote Double quote
- uncheck strings as factors

when your document is loaded you can simply remove the columns that now show as '?' You can see this is column 2 and column 4. If you have a dataframe, mydf, then you would delete the second column like this.

`mydf_new<-mydf[-2]`

You could do the same thing for the other column, which is now column 3.

Comment: This workaround is not bad, except for one thing: In the example I provided, there were a fixed number of columns with dashes. In reality, that number is not fixed... and it doesn't really address whether there is an encoding that would avoid such workarounds.