# Scala java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1

Tags: scala, character-encoding

I've found several questions with similar titles, but couldn't seem to use any to resolve my issue. I Can't seem to load my .csv file:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv")
```

Returns:

> java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1

So I tried:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("UTF-8", "C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv")
```

and got:

> java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv

I guess UTF-8 wouldn't work, if the file isn't in UTF-8 format, so that makes sense, but I don't know what to do next.

I've managed to discover the encoding is windows-1252 using:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv").codec.decodingReplaceWith("UTF-8")
```

But this didn't do what I had expected, which was convert the file to UTF-8. I have no Idea how to work with it.

Another thing I've tried was:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("windows-1252","C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv")
```

But that returned:

> java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know which to check as an answer. I wish I could check both....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try mapping your excel file to UTF-8 first and then try `val source = io.Source.fromFile("UTF-8", "C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv")`

To map to UTF-8 try:

> (1) Open an Excel file where you have the info (.xls, .xlsx)
>
> (2) In Excel, choose "CSV (Comma Delimited) (*.csv) as the file type
>   and save as that type.
>
> (3) In NOTEPAD (found under "Programs" and then Accessories in Start
>   menu), open the saved .csv file in Notepad
>
> (4) Then choose -> Save As..and at the bottom of the "save as" box,
>   there is a select box labelled as "Encoding". Select UTF-8 (do NOT use
>   ANSI or you lose all accents etc). After selecting UTF-8, then save
>   the file to a slightly different file name from the original.

This file is in UTF-8 and retains all characters and accents and can be imported, for example, into MySQL and other database programs.

Reference: [Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried opening it up in notepad directly, since I did try to see if saving it as a comma delimited file would work last night, and I got the same error. @ug_'s suggestion did work for me on the file I saved in UTF-8 format like you've suggested. No luck on the original file. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. Cheers

Comment: This way round: 'val source = io.Source.fromFile("C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv", "UTF-8")'

Answer (score 1):

Set up an `InputStreamReader` to correctly read windows-1252. Don't bother with intermediate UTF-8.

Comment: @ug_ has given me the answer in his comment, I had the parameters backwards. :P But I am curious, what do you mean by "Don't bother with intermediate UTF-8"? Does that have something to do with my apparent skill level? :)