# Scala programming: I'm trying to read a file

Tags: scala

When I run the code below, I get an error.
Can anyone please help me solve the problem?

Code:

```
object Tests {        
  new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()               
  val source = io.Source.fromFile("C://Users//AlphaLy//Desktop//INSURANCE.docx")  
}
```

Error:

> java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1 //| at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source) //| at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source) //| at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source) //| at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source) //| at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source) //| at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your post, as it is currently phrased, does not comply with the site's guidelines and is likely to be closed: it's missing a lot of information ("I get an error" - what is the error?) and some research (have you searched for how to read a file in Scala? There are many relevant answers on SO for that).

Comment: Here is the error:
 //> java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
 //| at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
 //| at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 //| at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
//| at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
//| at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)                                 //| at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44683465/edit) the post to add necessary information (instead of adding it in comments where it's easy to miss and hard to format clearly).

Comment: Also missing: what exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems that you're trying to read a _binary_ file (`.docx`) into a _String_, that's probably not useful even if you can get it to work; What do you expect `source` to contain?

Comment: I'm trying to read a file I saved at the path indicated in the code.

Comment: That did not answer my question; What are you trying to read the file _for_ -  do you expect to use it as a String (if so - you *can't*, if it's a `docx` file it's not a textual file)? Are you trying to load it into a _byte array_? what should `source` contain? It's impossible to answer your question as your intention is not clear.

Comment: I'm learning scala. I"m not an expert. I'm just trying to open the file and edit some lines. Just for learning purpose.

Comment: My question is simple. Why am I getting an error first place. It doesn't matter what I'm trying to do with the file.                                                 new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()  didn't give me any errors.           
Why the second one returns error? That's my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the file to *edit* lines, the file should contain *lines* to begin with;

A `docx` file is *binary* - it cannot be viewed as text and hence does not have "lines" at all; It cannot be read into a String in any sensible way - and that's what this exception means - `UnmappableCharacterException` because some characters (bytes) in the input cannot be mapped to any textual symbol.

Try saving a textual file format (e.g. using "Save as CSV" from Excel) and loading it; That should work, and if it doesn't - see [Scala java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141258/scala-java-nio-charset-unmappablecharacterexception-input-length-1) .

Comment: Thank you very much Tzach. I'll try. But the doc is a word document and I simply clicked on properties and copied the link. I didn't know it was a binary file. I'll try saving it differently and hope it will work. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Tzach. I saved it as a txt file and it's working. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear; To let other readers know this was helpful, you can upvote this answer and/or accept it