# How to read a CSV that includes Chinese characters in Rust?

Tags: csv, rust

When I read a CSV file that includes Chinese characters using [the csv crate](https://crates.io/crates/csv), it has a error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut rdr =
        csv::Reader::from_file("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.csv").unwrap().has_headers(false);
    for record in rdr.decode() {
        let (a, b): (String, String) = record.unwrap();
        println!("a:{},b:{}", a, b);
    }
    thread::sleep_ms(500000);
}
```

The error:

```
Running `target\release\rust_Work.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Decode("Could not convert bytes \'FromUtf8Error { bytes: [208, 213, 195, 251], error: Utf8Error { va
lid_up_to: 0 } }\' to UTF-8.")', ../src/libcore\result.rs:788
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
error: Process didn't exit successfully: `target\release\rust_Work.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

test.csv:

```
 1. 姓名   性别    年纪    分数     等级 
 2. 小二    男     12      88      良好
 3. 小三    男     13      89      良好 
 4. 小四    男     14      91      优秀
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't reproducible. Please provide the exact CSV data you're using and show the full output of your program. Please also explain what you expect to happen. The CSV crate should have no problems with Chinese characters, so you've likely misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the CSV not being encoded in UTF-8.  Most Rust code will *only* work with UTF-8.  If the file is encoded with UTF-16, UTF-32, Big5, GBK, or anything else, that is likely the problem.

Comment: @DK. shouldn't *something* have complained that it wasn't UTF-8 though?

Comment: @Shepmaster "program has a panic! bug" - that's vague enough that it *could* be a UTF-8 error... or pretty much anything else.  I'm guessing, here.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes, is so hard to realize that this is the error ¬¬_, you need super powers. Also, the answer must be the entire program working, even with a input that is space-separated-values. Is better to do all the work so the OP does nothing.

Comment: @freinn *even with a input that is space-separated-values* — then it wouldn't be a **comma**-separated value (CSV) file.

Comment: The term CSV is frequently used even if the delimiter isn't a comma. Modifying the delimiter is supported, but it is only allowed to be a single byte: https://docs.rs/csv/0.15.0/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.delimiter (The CSV crate reads "ASCII-compatible" data.)

Comment: I add the csv data image,thank you

Comment: @songroom No Shepmaster means you should copy-and-paste the content of `./data/simple.csv` here, and also paste the output of your program from the terminal.

Comment: how to copy csv file to here?

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to solve it. Thanks all.

```
extern crate csv;
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate encoding;
use encoding::{Encoding, EncoderTrap, DecoderTrap};
use encoding::all::{GB18030};
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let path = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.csv";
    let mut f = File::open(path).expect("cannot open file");
    let mut reader: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    f.read_to_end(&mut reader).expect("can not read file");
    let mut chars = String::new();
    GB18030.decode_to(&mut reader, DecoderTrap::Ignore, &mut chars);
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_string(chars).has_headers(true);
    for row in rdr.decode() {
        let (x, y, r): (String, String, String) = row.unwrap();
        println!("({}, {}): {:?}", x, y, r);
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what could be done to make the error message more clear:

> Decode("Could not convert bytes 'FromUtf8Error { bytes: [208, 213, 195, 251], error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 0 } }' to UTF-8.")

[`FromUtf8Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.FromUtf8Error.html) is documented in the standard library, and the text of the error says "Could not convert bytes to UTF-8" (although there's some extra detail in the middle).

Simply put, your data isn't in UTF-8 and it **must** be. That's all that the Rust standard library (and thus most libraries) really deal with. You will need to figure out what encoding it is in and then find some way of converting from that to UTF-8. There may be a [crate](https://crates.io/) to help with either of those cases.

Perhaps even better, you can save the file as UTF-8 from the beginning. Sadly, it's relatively common for people to hit this issue when using Excel, because [Excel does **not** have a way to easily export UTF-8 CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding). It always writes a CSV file in the system locale encoding.

Answer (score -3):

Part 1: Read Unicode (Chinese or not) characters:

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to use the [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) function that mutates the `String` you pass to it, appending the Unicode content of your file to that passed `String`:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("file.txt").unwrap();
    let mut buffer = String::new();

    f.read_to_string(&mut buffer);

    println!("{}", buffer)
}
```

Part 2: Parse a CSV file, its delimiter being a **','**:

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("file.txt").unwrap();
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let delimiter = ",";

    f.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
    let modified_buffer = buffer.replace("\n", delimiter);
    let mut regex_str = "([^".to_string();

    regex_str.push_str(delimiter);
    regex_str.push_str("]+)");

    let mut final_part = "".to_string();
    final_part.push_str(delimiter);
    final_part.push_str("?");

    regex_str.push_str(&final_part);

    let regex_str_copy = regex_str.clone();
    regex_str.push_str(&regex_str_copy);
    regex_str.push_str(&regex_str_copy);

    let re = Regex::new(&regex_str).unwrap();

    for cap in re.captures_iter(&modified_buffer) {
        let (s1, s2, dist): (String, String, usize) =
            (cap[1].to_string(), cap[2].to_string(), cap[3].parse::<usize>().unwrap());
         println!("({}, {}): {}", s1, s2, dist);
    }
}
```

Sample input and output [here](http://pastebin.com/cVUQm6eS)

Comment: This doesn't parse CSV.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 and? The question ask for **reading** chinese Unicode characters.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 yes, and my answer reads any kind of file, being csv or not.

Comment: The OP's code includes the line like `let (s1, s2, dist): (String, String, usize) = record.unwrap()` where each record's fields are parsed to the user-specified types. Could you update your answer to show the equivalent?

Comment: @Shepmaster done. Not the most beautiful code but it works.

Comment: This is still wrong. It doesn't parse CSV which is what the **OP wants** because the question starts with "How to read a **csv**".

Comment: @BurntSushi5 fine now?

Comment: can i read the csv file that includes Chinese characters using the CSV crate?