# Excel: How to save csv with single quote quote character instead of double quote

Tags: excel, csv

My default it seems that Excel saves a csv with a double quote as a quote character... so a test field like this:

```
{"abc":1234}
```

gets saved as

```
"{""abc"":1234}"
```

If I could tell Excel to use a single quote (') as a quote character it would be saved the first way... I need this functionality because a third party program (Bloomberg) doesn't recognize the " as an escape character and imports the 2nd way literally.

Is there a way to tell Excel to use a different character for the quote character?

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding?rq=1. Seems its tricky: best is to get Excel 2016 and save as Unicode csv.

Comment: @Brian Rice You may have to go for a work around as discussed in these references. <https://superuser.com/questions/867101/excel-adds-double-quotes-on-csv-export> and <https://superuser.com/questions/349882/how-to-avoid-double-quotes-when-saving-excel-file-as-unicode>

Answer (score 0):

An escape character escapes the `"` inside a field, so using `'` would (or should) generate:

```
"{'"abc'":1234}"
```

However, you could try to use `'` as the quote char which should generate:

```
'{"abc":12,34}'   // if there's a separator in the field
```

or possibly:

```
{"abc":1234}      // if there's no separator in the field
```

Alternatively, if you can be sure there are no comma's inside the fields you could use no quoting at all around the fields.

Comment: You're right, I update my question to use "quote character" instead of "escape character".

Comment: But, how can I define a single quote as the quote character in Excel.