# Microsof Excel 2016 Unicode (UTF-8) does not work

Tags: excel, ms-office

I searched all around internet how to save CVS file as Unicode (UTF-8), but it still does not work, whenever i save, and open the file, there is ????? instead of letter that are UTF-8.

[image: Screenshot when saving as Unicode (UTF-8)]

Has anyone ever had this issue? how can i solve this?

Comment: Under which software do you save the CSV? With which software do you want to read it? Are they both the same Excel 2016 installation, or not?

Comment: Windows 10. Yes same. I just save and open again.

Comment: Those are the Web options. AFAIK, they do not affect CSVs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel to CSV with UTF8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

This has been annoying short coming of Excel for a long time.

A way to work around this issue, is to do the following:

1. Save as... Unicode text (*.txt).  Make sure to keep the extension as txt (or at least not csv).  It will be saved with tabs instead of commas separating the columns.
2. Open the document.  You will be prompted with an import wizard, like so:

[image]

3. For File origin, choose 65001: Unicode (UTF-8)
4. For the rest of the options, choose the common sense options.

You will have your document back, ready to edit, with the proper unicode text intact.