# Problem with german umlauts in generated CSV file using Grails

Tags: grails, character-encoding

Problem with german umlauts in generated CSV file using Grails

Hi,

I have a problem with the german umlauts like ä,ö,ü in generated CSV files using Grails, here is the snippet of my code

```
def report = {
    //....
    response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + params.dateiname + "");   
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")   
    response.outputStream << datalist  // in datalist are the data in CSV format like "File";"Date";"Customer" etc.
}
```

After calling the closure and saving the file the german umlauts are diplayed wrong with Excel, but they are displayed correct when I open the file with notepad.

Does anyone have an idea of this Problem?

Thanks in advance!

mozilla20

Comment: Where is the data which contains the Umlauts stored? Is it read from the DB or any other file?

Comment: the data which contains the Umlauts are retrieved from the MySQL DB.

Comment: And what's the encoding of the MySQl DB/Tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, Excel assumes ANSI CSV encoding. Explicit BOM helps *sometimes*: [Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files/155176#155176)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added BOM to the file, and it works now. Thank you very much!