# Generated .csv file display Â£ instead of £ symbol in csv file

Tags: excel, csv

```
"Item Name","Item Number",Description,"Cost Price","Unit Price",Count,"Reorder Level"
" CHEFS TROUSERS BLUE/WHITE",21013,,£5.67,£12.50,1.00,0.00
...
...
```

A csv file with the above format incorrectly displays a euro symbol in excel as Â£. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: displays correctly for me in Excel

Comment: See the answer to this question:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097