# Reading line by line from file

Tags: c, linux, readfile

I'm trying to read line by line from a file but getting wierd prints all the time.
I'm getting a lot of prints that look like squares divided to little 4 squares and in them 0s.

Here is my code:
(I read only 3 lines)
(If I dont write the if(...) break; it prints the files as is and doesnt print wierd symbols)

```
while(i<3)    
    {   
        while(read(fdin,buff,1)>0 )    
        {    
            if (strcmp(buff,"\n")==0)    
                break;      
            strcat(ch,buff);   
        }    
        printf("%s\n","********");   
        printf("%s\n",ch);    
        memset(ch,NULL,100);    
        i++;    
    }
```

The file I read: (I read paths)

```
/home/user/Desktop/dir1
/home/user/Desktop/dir2
/home/user/Desktop/dir3
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the file you're reading?

Comment: Do you initialize your string `ch` with a 0 ? strcat will append at the end of the c string, that is, starting at the first 0.

Comment: Your input file likely has non-printable characters. Please provide the input file.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I check if the return value of read is bigger the 0, every iteration  only read 1 character .@Pradhan I provided the imput file

Comment: `strcmp` and `strcat` expect a null-terminated array of characters. You only have an array of characters that's as long as the return value of the `read` call. (I know the return value is just going to be `1`, but it still needs to make an appearance somewhere.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB Thank you, it works now!
I didnt think of it at all. If you want you can answer te question and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just reading one character at a time (which is not very efficient, since each `read` is a system call), try this code instead, which doesn't use any C string operations and just inspects the character on the fly and builds up the resulting line as it goes along.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char s[100], * p = s, * e = s + 100;

for (;;)
{
    if (p == e)
    {
        /* overflow */
        fprintf(stderr, "Input line too long.\n";)
        abort();
    }

    errno = 0
    n = read(fdin, p, 1);

    if (n == 0 || *p == '\n')
    {
        *p = '\0';
        printf("Line: '%s'\n", s);

        // or: fwrite(s, 1, p - s, stdout)

        if (n == 0)
        {
            /* end of file */
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            /* reset, next line */
            p = s;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        abort();
    }
    else
    {
        ++p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Maybe [Reading text files of unknown encoding in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872701/reading-text-files-of-unknown-encoding-in-c) can help, although it's for C++.

Comment: If I dont write the if(...) break; it prints the files as is and doesnt print wierd symbols. I also updated my question. but that way i cant divide it to lines