# Problems with special characters in Microsoft Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv, io, special-characters

In a Java portlet I'm offering files to download through the [serveResource(...)](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/ResourceServingPortlet.html#serveResource%28javax.portlet.ResourceRequest,%20javax.portlet.ResourceResponse%29) method.

I'm calling

```
response.getPortletOutputStream().write(byteArray);
```

This `byte` array contains some special characters in German, for example `Ä`, `Ü` or `ö`. The file format of the resulting file is csv.

When I'm opening the file in a text editor, the special characters are displayed correctly.

However when I open them in Microsoft Excel, they're displayed as `Ã¼` or `ÃŸ`.

Do you have any ideas of what could be the cause of this problem?

Notepad++ displays the file as

> ANSI as UTF-8

Comment: Do you write an UTF-8 BOM (byte order mark) at the start of your CSV? If not, Excel might just not know it's an UTF-8 file. Other editors might scan the text and try to determine the encoding from the content, if the BOM is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: [Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

Basically, you'd need to add a byte order mark (BOM) to your CSV file.

Comment: I'm writing the BOM with `outputStream.write(239); outputStream.write(187); outputStream.write(191);` now. See also http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bom.html