# Export CSV not displaying special characters like α ,β etc

Tags: c#, csv

My Site has an export csv functionality which exports the details of the site in the csv format. My code handles the special characters like Å ,ĉ but not the greek characters. I am using the following code to generate the csv.

```
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
Response.Charset = "iso-8859-1";
```

I have tried all the options of charset as well as the contentEncoding but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an encoding that can encode all the characters you need, and one that will be recognised by whichever program loads your file.

You are currently using a fixed length 8 bit encoding and there are no fixed length 8 bit encodings that can encode all the characters you need. So you need to use something like UTF-8 or UTF-16 to encode your content.

On the flip side, many common .csv file readers don't support anything other than fixed length 8 bit encodings.

I think your next step is to find a Unicode encoding that is understood by enough .csv file readers to satisfy your needs. If you can find a suitable encoding then you are done. If no encoding meets your needs then I suspect that you need to use something other than .csv.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, if your problem concerns Microsoft Excel, then see this question:

[Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

> There is a known bug where Excel, upon opening a UTF8 csv files via
>   file association, assumes that they are ASCII, disregarding the
>   presence of the UTF8 BOM.

It would seem that there is also a fix for older Excel's using UTF-16 but this would mean including download links for CSV and Excel.

An alternative is to instruct the user to save and import the file as UTF-8 which appears to force Excel to handle the text properly.

I don't think there's a silver bullet for this one.