# XSLT output BOM character visible in Excel

Tags: excel, xslt, byte-order-mark

My Java EE web app uses XSLT transformation to produce CSV reports.
If I specify "UTF-16" as the encoding on the XSLT (which seems to be the only way to handle accented characters in the XML) then I get a  byte-order-mark character at the start of the CSV output
From what I understand, this is correct behavior.  The problem is that this BOM character is visible if the CSV is opened in Excel (appears as: þÿ), but not if I open it in a proper text editor ;)
How can I hide or omit this character so it isn't visible when the file is opened in Excel?

Comment: Why does UTF-8 not work for you?  It should be able to encode the accented characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to specify which version of XSLT you are using.

If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can suppress the BOM using the [xsl:output](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output) element. For example...

```
<xsl:output method="xml" byte-order-mark="no" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

### What if you are using XSLT 1.0?

Here are two options:

1. Upgrade to XSLT 2.0
2. Upgrade your Excel to 2007 (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files) for why)

Comment: omitting the BOM totally as you suggest does 'work' insofar as it's no longer visible in Excel.  Unfortunately it also means that normal text editors don't realise the file is double-byte encoding (a NULL character appears before every character).  I realise this is the nature of encoding, but I just wonder if I can get the best of both worlds somehow..

Comment: Any decent text editor can auto-recognise encoding (UTF-8 vrs UTF-16) from text content, even without a BOM. If your "normal" text editor cant, it is rubbish. Upgrade your text editor!

Answer (score 1):

if you are writing a CSV file the method should probably not be "xml" as Sean B. Durkin suggests.

i recommend this configuration to make a CSV that will correctly open in Excel

```
<xsl:output method="text" byte-order-mark="yes" encoding="UTF-16LE" indent="no"/>
```

**Other tips when using XSLT to generate a CSV:**

You can use TAB characters even though CSV means "comma separated value"

I find the data i separate is often void of tabs but has the occasional comma.

and `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` is a way to add a line-break.

you probably want to escape linebreaks that occur in the values you use, like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($foo,'\n','\\n')"/>
```

and of course, you will quickly notice that if you open the file in Excel, it becomes **read-only** which is a bother when you try to generate the file again while it is still open.  unlike most text editors which simply tell you the file has changed, and offer to reload it.

-

I realize this question is dated and answered already, but I hope this helps a future someone.