# Rails Excel 2007 export: Add Byte Order Mark to .erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, excel-2007

I am exporting data to Excel by making an erb template for the xls file.  This is following the procedure recommended in [Railscast 362](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast) for making properly encoded exports.

The output opens fine in Excel for Mac 2011, but in Excel 2007 characters like é appear as Ã© because the UTF-8 encoded file is being interpreted by Excel as Latin1.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155176/1450420) Excel 2007 will correctly interpret an UTF-8 file if it starts with the right Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Taking at a look at the hex version of the output it seems that indeed it doesn’t have a BOM.

There are a number of sources (like [this Plataformatec blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/09/exporting-data-to-csv-and-excel-in-your-rails-app/)) that explain how to add a BOM when rendering the data inline in the controller:

```
BOM = "\377\376"
BOM + Iconv.conv('utf-16le', 'utf8', data)
```

My question is – is there a way of getting the template correctly interpreted by Excel 2007? Or should I go back to rendering the data in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Excel makes this so hard, but they do.

I tried using that code myself when I ran into this encoding problem. I couldn't figure out how to apply it to what I was working with. So I did a workaround instead.

I downloaded the CSV file as indicated in the Railscast. I then opened the file with TextWrangler, which encodes it properly. Then, I copied and pasted the contents into a blank Excel document (which reads it as text, and thus, does not mess up the encoding). Following that, I selected the column all the data fell under, and then in the menubar selected "Data -> Text to Columns". I then selected a delimited list and entered a comma as the delimiter (it defaults to a tab). Then I finished it up and voila, there is a properly formatted Excel doc.