# Google App engine python writing csv in arabic

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to write a CSV in Arabic script. I have encoded the string to utf-8 and wrote it in the csv.

The problem is if I open the file in csv it shows strange characters like `Ø¢Ù„Ø² 
Ø³Ù†Ø¯ÙˆÙŠØªØ´ ÙƒØ§ÙÙŠÙ‡` however if I open the file in notepad++ it shows the expected arabic text.

i checked notepad ++ and converted the encoding to utf-8 instead of utf-8 without BOM , now its working fine in csv reader(excel) too. so what should i do to set encoding to "utf-8 with BOM" in app engine

i am using unicodecsv.writer to write the csv

```
writer = unicodecsv.writer(self.response.out)
row = []
row.append(transaction.name.encode('utf8'))
writer.writerow(row)
```

the data to be written is taken from the datastore

Comment: **How** do you open the CSV file? If you have code, can you show us?

Comment: i have pasted the code

Comment: Not the code *writing* the CSV; notepad seems to have been able to read it. :-) How do you *read* the CSV?

Comment: oh sorry , i mean when i manually open the generated csv.

Comment: Open it with *what*? Excel? That program always tries to open CSVs with the local codepage instead.

Comment: See [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256)

Comment: i have updated the question i have sort of figured out that problem is due to BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a CSV with UTF-8 BOM, simply write the BOM first; you can use [`codecs.BOM_UTF8`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM_UTF8) for that:

```
import codecs

self.response.out.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
row = []
row.append(transaction.name.encode('utf8'))
writer.writerow(row)
```

[Excel 2007 and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files) pick up on the BOM and correctly open such a CSV file with UTF-8. Silly Microsoft!

Comment: you rock man !! just a correction it should be 
    import codecs and  codecs.BOM_UTF8. Thanks alot