# export CSV with Hebrew char that can be opened by Excel

Tags: java, excel, csv

I know there is a lot of similar question but I still cannot find a solution,

my code:

```
    resp.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
    resp.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    resp.addHeader("Expires", "0");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
```

The result is opened as a gibrish text instead of hebrew in excell.

How should I change this text so the result CSV can be opened in Excell (without importing it to excell)?

i.e. what charset should I used, and what is the correct code to generate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
sb.insert(0, '\uFEFF');
resp.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
```

This inserts a BOM character, a zero-width space, to mark the text as Unicode. It is redundant, even ugly. But in this way Excel & Notepad won't mistake the encoding for the platform encoding.

Caveat:

Now cell A1 cannot contain a number.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the encoding headers in your response won't be associated with the attachment; they're only for use when reading the response body.

Excel is oddly bad at handling UTF-8 encoded CSV files. [Here's a good answer from the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155176/1308699) on convincing it to behave; the other option would be to re-encode your CSV in Windows-1252.