# How to create UTF-8 compliant CVS file with javascript that open automatically in Mac Excel 2011

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, utf-8, export-to-csv

How to you get this chrome API to download a CSV file that can be opened in Excel.

```
var csv = '123, 123, 美国'

chrome.downloads.download({
     url: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURI(csv),
     filename: name + '.csv',
     saveAs: true
}
```

The root cause of the difficulty is that CSV file does not have any notion of encoding built in. And Excel when encounters a file with extension CSV it assumes it is single byte order and opens it that way. If you have double byte characters encoded in UTF-8 in your file Excel opens that file with garbage characters.

The answers in this question suggest that adding BOM to for UTF-8 will clue in Excel that this is a UTF-8 file.

[Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

However no matter what we tried we could not get Excel to recognize the file Automatically. Using text import wizard or other text editors it works.

Here is a tool that lets you try various combinations. But none of the worked for us: http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/HM4rW/show/light/

Comment: Your fiddle code seems to insert the BOM just fine. If static files generated with other text editors do work, you should compare both files and see if there's a difference.

Comment: Interesting problem. But the Fiddle example just works for me. If I put any characters under name, city, state (like those Chinese from your example or anything else really) and click download, then both under OS X with Apache Open Office Calc and under Linux with Libre Office Calc, I'm offered the the Text Import dialogue, and when selecting UTF-8 for encoding, the same characters appear in Excel.

Comment: I am running Office 2011 on OSX and BOM does not cause Excel to auto recognize the file. I tested it with HEX editors and no luck.

Comment: Support for a UTF-8 BOM was added in Excel (Mac) 15.

Comment: UTF-16 LE with BOM works for me on Mac Excel 2011. Of course, you'll have to encode it first with a suitable encoder.