# Pandas DataFrame's accented characters appearing garbled in Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, non-ascii-characters

With:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the top of my .ipynb, Jupyter is now displaying accented characters correctly.

When I export to csv (with `.to_csv()`) a `pandas` data frame containing accented characters:

[image]

... the characters do not render properly when the csv is opened in Excel.

[image]

This is the case whether I set the `encoding='utf-8'` or not. Is pandas/python doing all that it can here, and this is an Excel issue? Or can something be done before the export to csv?

- Python: 2.7.10
- Pandas: 0.17.1
- Excel: Excel for Mac 2011

Comment: Most likely it's an Excel issue.  Check the csv import options; one of them should be character encoding.

Comment: It seems that `to_excel()` does not exhibit the same problem, though I'm forced to export as a .xls, which is not ideal.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here (use the Import Text wizard): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files

Answer (score 9):

If you want to keep accents, try with encoding='iso-8859-1'

```
df.to_csv(path,encoding='iso-8859-1',sep=';')
```

Comment: this may work, but it feels like a hack since utf-8 is a better universal standard

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem, also on a Mac. I noticed that the unicode string showed up fine when I opened the csv in TextEdit, but showed up garbled when I opened in Excel.

Thus, I don't think there is any way successfully export unicode to Excel with `to_csv`, but I'd expect the default `to_excel` writer to suffice.

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same inconvenience. When I checked the Dataframe in the Jupyter notebook I saw that everything was in order.

The problem happens when I try to open the file directly (as it has a .csv extension Excel can open it directly).

The solution for me was to open a new blank excel workbook, and import the file from the "Data" tab, like this:

- Import External Data
- Import Data from text
- I choose the file
- In the import wizard window, where it says "File origin" in the drop-down list, I chose the "65001 : Unicode (utf-8)"

Then i just choose the right delimiter, and that was it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think using a different excel writer helps, recommending `xlsxwriter`

```
import pandas as pd
df = ...
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this function for your columns if you can't get Excel to cooperate.  It will remove the accents using the `unicodedata` library:

```
import unicodedata

def remove_accents(input_str):

    if type(input_str) == unicode:
        nfkd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
        return u"".join([c for c in nfkd_form if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
    else:
        return input_str
```

Comment: I actually need to maintain the accents, though your function may come in handy in the future, thanks. Not sure if it's doing what is intended though. Tried a quick test: http://pastebin.com/gA8FuGDq

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and writing to .xlsx and renaming to .csv didn't solve the problem (for application-specific reasons I won't go into here), nor was I able to successfully use an alternate encoding as Juliana Rivera recommended. 'Manually' writing the data as text worked for me.

```
with open(RESULT_FP + '.csv', 'w+') as rf:
    for row in output:
        row = ','.join(list(map(str, row))) + '\n'
        rf.write(row)
```

Sometimes I guess you just have to go back to basics.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when attempting to `read_json` followed by a `to_excel`:

```
df = pandas.read_json(myfilepath)
# causes garbled characters
df.to_excel(sheetpath, encoding='utf8') 
# also causes garbled characters
df.to_excel(sheetpath, encoding='latin1')
```

Turns out, if I load the json manually with the `json` module first, and then export with `to_excel`, the issue doesn't occur:

```
with open(myfilepath, encoding='utf8') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

df = pandas.DataFrame(j)
df.to_excel(sheetpath, encoding='utf8')
```