# write to file in hebrew in android (java)

Tags: java, android, file, utf, hebrew

i work on a project of contacts 
i copy all the contacts and write them to csv file and then i upload them to firebase .

when i open this file (in any device) , i see that the contacts that writed with hebrew letters look weird.

this how its look : 
[image]

this is my code :

```
  public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) throws Exception {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ProjectContacts");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        OutputStreamWriter writer =new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);//
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Start upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //UploadCsvFile(gpxfile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**sBody contain hebrew letters**

i wish someone can help my . thanks.

Comment: Excel is notoriously poor at encoding detection. Please load the file in Notepad++ and report the results.

Comment: i dont understand ..

Comment: Your issue is related to the encoding of the file. It's likely that your csv file is UTF-8 encoded (You should force the encoding!). By default Excel does not parse in UTF-8 (unless you tell it or the file contains a UTF-8 BOM). Load the CSV in an editor which does a better job of reading UTF-8.

Comment: you mean that i write to txt file and then chenge it to csv ?

Comment: i open it in txt file and it show the hebrew perfect , how can i show the hebrew in the csv file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible your CSV is not in UTF-8, so you might want to do as Alastair suggested and either open it up in something like Google Sheets or OpenOffice, or use a simple text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text 3 to find out what encoding your file is using, then import the CSV into Excel using the process outlined in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/9374673).

Of course, you could also add a UTF-8 BOM to your file, as mentioned in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155176/9374673) Then Excel should automatically recognize the UTF-8 encoding and display any special characters properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your data file is UTF-8. Excel does not read UTF-8 if you just "open" the file. What you should do is:

- Open a NEW file in excel
- Click on the top-left cell (or top-right if you excel is in Hebrew)
- Click on the Data tab in the ribbon, and choose "From Text"
- In the import Wizard:

  - Select "Delmited"
  - Make sure to select "UTF-8" Encoding ("File Origin")
  - Next
  - Select "Comma"
  - Finish

[image: Encoding Selection Image]