# How To Specify Character Encoding For Text File To Insert Into ZIP

Tags: marklogic

I have a requirement to create CSV (Comma Separated Values) files and place them in a ZIP file, using **XQuery**. This is easy enough to do, except that I need the CSV files in the ZIP file to be encoded with **ISO-8859-1** instead of **UTF-8** (because Excel expects that encoding!).

When I download a CSV file directly, I can use `xdmp:set-response-encoding("ISO-8859-1")` to get what I want. But is there an equivalent technique to set the encoding of a text `{ "..." }` node that I insert into the ZIP?

Comment: Are you sure that you must have that encoding? Excel should work with UTF-8 if there is a BOM https://stackoverflow.com/a/155176/14419

Comment: You might be right, and I already tried to add a BOM within my XQuery code, but it just added those bytes as characters to the start of the output - so a way to achieve THAT might be just what I needed. But it is an interesting question even if that works for Excel. I may come up with future requirements where a non-UTF-8 encoding is definitely required. So still interested if there is a solution to that original question too!

Comment: `text()` will be maintained as UTF-8. When reading data in other encodings, it will be transcoded. Not sure if there might be some tricks to creating as a `binary()` node to put in the zip, or request the CSV from MarkLogic with the desired encoding and then perform the zip externally.....

Comment: OK, so building on that idea, I suppose I could write the text node to the file system, in a different encoding, then read it back as a binary node so the content is not modified in nany way, then add the binary to the ZIP contents, within MarkLogic. No need for an external ZIP tool if I can get that to work - I will certainly try it!

Comment: That's the best workaround I know of:  write to fs, read back as binary.

Comment: That is what I did and it works.

let $RandomFile := "ABCDEF.txt"
let $OutputTextNode := text { $CSVData }            
let $Save := xdmp:save("C:\XXX\" || $RandomFile, $OutputTextNode, <options xmlns="xdmp:save"><output-encoding>iso-8859-1</output-encoding></options>)
let $OutputBinaryNode := xdmp:document-get("C:\XXX\" || $RandomFile, <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get"><format>binary</format></options>)
let $Delete := xdmp:filesystem-file-delete("C:\XXX\" || $RandomFile)
return
  $OutputBinaryNode