# Line-feed is identified as Windows style, despite using \n

Tags: php, csv, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm creating on-the-fly a CSV file to download via a hyperlink, using the following code:

```
                $content = <<<END
data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\xEF\xBB\xBF"Date","Number of items sold","Number of orders","Average net sales amount","Coupon amount","Shipping amount","Gross sales amount","Net sales amount","Refund amount"\n
"2022-4-26","0","0","7.82","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
"2022-4-27","0","0","0","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
"2022-4-28","0","0","0","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
"2022-4-29","3","3","0","0.00","9.00","63.73","54.73","0.00"\n
"2022-4-30","0","0","0","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
"2022-5-1","0","0","0","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
"2022-5-2","0","0","7.82","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"\n
END;
                $link = ' <a href="' . htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES) . '">' . __('Download CSV', 'custom-code') . '</a>';
```

The problem is that although I'm using `\n` at the end of each line, the produced file is still identified as having CRLF style of new lines.

[Here](https://easyupload.io/m/sivbzj) you can find two files, where `report-7day-2022-05-02.csv` is created by JS and is identified correctly as LF, and `aaaaaa.csv` is my file - created by the code above - and is somehow mistakenly identified as CRLF.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this a problem for you?  Your HEREDOC string already has (hidden) line breaks.  You are manually adding `\n` (visibly) as well.  Did you try removing your visible `\n`s?

Comment: @mickmackusa my problem is that I'm doing all this to 'imitate" in PHP the `report-7day-2022-05-02.csv`, which is created on-the-fly by JS. But the two files differ in their line breaks. Result is that, i.e. MS Excel, correctly opens the first one in multiple lines, whereas it opens my `aaaaa.csv` with all its contents in a single line...
https://i.ibb.co/N3K870s/Screenshot-2022-05-02-232539.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/j4FM9c1/Screenshot-2022-05-02-232607.jpg

Comment: If you want explicit controller of the line terminators, don't press Enter when handwriting your data.  Implode an array of rows with `\r\n` (or `\n`) -- if that is what you are after.  In both cases, it doesn't look like your columns are being respected.  This may be a secondary issue.  Do you actually need that BOM before the first cell, and the header info?

Comment: @mickmackusa I've literally tried every combination. Literal line breaks in the Heredoc, with or without additional `\n`'s at the end of each line, then tried even `\r`'s and `\r\n`'s... Nothing changed... They always appear in the same line! The BOM, TBH, I don't need it. I found it there in the JS code (`csv_data = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent( csv_data );`) and thought to use it in my PHP code too...

Comment: I feel like `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,` is intended to be a "header" declaration, but it is actually written in the "body" of the document. This is interfering with the intention of using the BOM because the BOM must be at the very start of the "body" of the document.  This is not likely a solution for the line breaking problem, but it seems important to address.  Maybe gather some insights from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648671/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa it's an extract of code off of the official release of WooCommerce, more specifically in woocommerce/assets/js/admin/reports.js Ln.252
About my problem, I've in the meantime tried your `implode()`ed array solution, with `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, even two new lines, like `\n\n`, with no difference! Would you like to give it a try?

Comment: @mickmackusa if you want to give it a try...
`<?php
$content = array(
    "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\xEF\xBB\xBF\"Date\",\"Number of items sold\",\"Number of orders\",\"Average net sales amount\",\"Coupon amount\",\"Shipping amount\",\"Gross sales amount\",\"Net sales amount\",\"Refund amount\"",
    "\"2022-4-26\",\"0\",\"0\",\"7.82\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\"",
    "\"2022-4-27\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\",\"0.00\"",
);
echo ' <a href="' . htmlspecialchars(implode("\x0D\x0A", $content)) . '" download="aaaaaa.csv">Download</a>';`

Comment: @mickmackusa in my code above I even used the UTF-8 representation of `\r\n` (`\x0D\x0A`) just in case... But with no difference either... I'm officially clueless...