# Json to csv with cyrillic

Tags: php, json, csv, export-to-csv, cyrillic

This is my php code:

```
<?php 
$jsonData = file_get_contents("1.json");
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonData);

$csv = '1.csv';
$fileCsv = fopen($csv, 'w');
foreach($jsonDecoded as $i){
    fputcsv($fileCsv, $i);
}

fclose($fileCsv);

?>
```

In 1.json I have data written in cyrillic. Whene 1.csv is opened via Excel, there is a problem with decoding it. It shows me non-cyrillic random symbols. Why is it so? How can I fix it?

I'm not sure where this problem comes from. It could be just problem with Excel? I'm using Excel 2016.

The desired ecxel:
[image]

How it actually looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/6002256/367456 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/155097/367456 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A utf8 CSV file has a Byte Order Mark as its first three octets. These are the hex values 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF.  So you can do:

```
$fileCsv = fopen($csv, 'w');
fprintf($fileCsv, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
foreach($jsonDecoded as $i){
    fputcsv($fileCsv, $i);
}

fclose($fileCsv);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Just one last question. What does chr(0xEF) mean?

Comment: it's converting the hex value 0xEF to a character so we can write it to the file.